# I didn't give enough information to answer my question, should I withdraw it?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, deleted-questions, question-quality

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23506039/619177).  In working on the issue today, I realized that the problem was due to a mismatch between the names of my form controls as given in the VBA and as given on the form itself.  Because I didn't include the form control names in my question, there would be no way for another Stack Overflow user to answer this question successfully.

Should I delete or close the question?  Or add the correct answer, change the question to include the info about the control names, and leave it up?

Comment: I rolled back the edit which removed the link to the question.  While the question may have been deleted by the OP, high reputation users can still view it.  As such, the link may still add benefit to a Meta discussion surrounding it.  (Unfortunately, the rollback edit didn't allow me to type in a reason like a normal edit does.)

Comment: @JeffGohlke Hack to provide a rollback reason (or, in general, to modify your edit reason after making an edit): after rolling back (or submitting your edit with a reason you're not satisfied with), edit the post to add a space on the end. Then edit the post again to remove the space, and change the edit message as you do so. The edits will get collapsed together as long as they're within 5 minutes of each other, and the final edit message will be used. For rollbacks in particular, you can also use the 'edit' link next to the target revision instead of the 'rollback' one to add a custom msg.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Add the answer as an answer and edit the question if that would make the topic valuable for someone else. If that can't be done, delete it.

Answer (score 18):

It sounds to me like this is unlikely to be useful to anyone else in its current form, which would call for a deletion.

If you edit the question to add the relevant information then answer the question, it still sounds like it will not be useful to anyone else, which, again, means deletion would be appropriate.

However, if you feel that you can edit it with the necessary information and make it useful for others then I would edit and answer with your solution.

Ultimately, it is your decision but if it isn't edited then it will possibly be closed by the community eventually.